# Нажатие стрелок С++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Решил написать консольного Марио и столкнулся с такой проблемой: как отлавливать событие нажатия стрелок на клавиатуре, скажем через WinApi или при помощи стандартных средств с++? (Windows)

```
void Game::input()
{
    Key key;
    char c;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> c;
        switch (c)
        {
        case up_key:
            movePlayer(player_pos + new Position(0, -3));
            break;
        case down_key:
            movePlayer(player_pos + new Position(0, 1));
            break;
        case right_key:
            movePlayer(player_pos + new Position(1, 0));
            break;
        case left_key:
            movePlayer(player_pos - new Position(1, 0));
            break;
        }
        show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Стандартными средствами C++ вообще никак. Только средствами ОС (или сторонними библиотеками). Укажите ОС, в которой работаете, а там уже и помогут вам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, в консоли Windows можно воспользоваться не входящей в стандарт, но входящей в SDK `getch()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int k1, k2;
    for(;;)
    {
        k1 = _getch();
        if (k1 == 0xE0 || k1 == 0x00)
        {
            k2 = _getch();
            switch(k2)
            {
            case 0x4B: printf("Left  on %s kbd\n", k1 ? "main" : "extended"); break;
            case 0x48: printf("Up    on %s kbd\n", k1 ? "main" : "extended"); break;
            case 0x4D: printf("Right on %s kbd\n", k1 ? "main" : "extended"); break;
            case 0x50: printf("Down  on %s kbd\n", k1 ? "main" : "extended"); break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Harry, это конечно хорошо, но такое), есть еще варианты?)

Comment: И что же вас устроит? Это самый простой вариант, какой только можно придумать... Хотите - смотрите тут сами: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Harry, да понял, ваш вариант и вправду самый простой)

Answer (score 2):

Хуки нужно юзать, хуки )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x050

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    BOOL fEatKeystroke = FALSE;

    if( nCode == HC_ACTION )
    {
        switch( wParam )
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
            case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
            case WM_KEYUP:
            case WM_SYSKEYUP:
            PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;

            if( fEatKeystroke = (p->scanCode == 0x48) )
            {     
                printf( "UP\n" );
                /*keybd_event( 'B', 0, 0, 0 );
                keybd_event( 'B', 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );*/
                break;
            }
            if( fEatKeystroke = (p->scanCode == 0x4B) )
            {     
                printf( "LEFT\n" );
                /*keybd_event( 'B', 0, 0, 0 );
                keybd_event( 'B', 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );*/
                break;
            }
            if( fEatKeystroke = (p->scanCode == 0x4D) )
            {     
                printf( "DOWN\n" );
                /*keybd_event( 'B', 0, 0, 0 );
                keybd_event( 'B', 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );*/
                break;
            }
            if( fEatKeystroke = (p->scanCode == 0x50) )
            {     
                printf( "RIGHT\n" );
                /*keybd_event( 'B', 0, 0, 0 );
                keybd_event( 'B', 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );*/
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return(fEatKeystroke ? 1 : CallNextHookEx( NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam ));
}

int main()
{
    // Install the low-level keyboard & mouse hooks
    HHOOK hhkLowLevelKybd = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, 0, 0 );

    // Keep this app running until we're told to stop
    MSG msg;
    while( !GetMessage( &msg, NULL, NULL, NULL ) )
    {    //this while loop keeps the hook
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx( hhkLowLevelKybd );

    return(0);
}
```