# Проблема с получением символа с помощью _getche()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, поток-ввода

Нижеприведенная программа - часть программы консольного меню ввода данных. При переключении на поля "ИМЯ"(вторая строчка формы) или ТАРИФ(третья строчка формы) с помощью клавиш клавиатуры - стрелки вверх(VK_UP) или вниз(VK_DOWN) программа работает не так как задумывалась . Проблема в том, что в поля ввода (в соответственно name и tariff - строки которые хранят значения соответствующих полей) заносится символ "P"(при нажатии стрелки вниз) или символ "H"(при нажатии стрелки вверх).
Как это можно исправить?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

void gotoxy(short x, short y) 
{
    HANDLE    StdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD    coord = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(StdOut, coord);
}
int wherex()
{
    HANDLE                        StdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO    csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(StdOut, &csbi);
    return int(csbi.dwCursorPosition.X);
}
int wherey()
{
    HANDLE                        StdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO    csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(StdOut, &csbi);
    return int(csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y);
}

void valueInputMenu(HANDLE& hConsoleHandle);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    // Скрыть курсор
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO curs = { 0 };
    curs.dwSize = sizeof(curs);
    curs.bVisible = FALSE;
    ::SetConsoleCursorInfo(::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &curs);

    HANDLE hConsoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    valueInputMenu(hConsoleHandle);

    return 0;
}
void valueInputMenu(HANDLE& hConsoleHandle)
{
    int selectedMenuItem = 1;
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "  ВВЕДИТЕ ДАННЫЕ ДОБАВЛЯЕМОГО УЗЛА (АБОНЕНТА)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  НОМЕР: +_ (___) ___-__-__" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    ИМЯ: __________________" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  ТАРИФ: __________________" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  ДОБАВИТЬ УЗЕЛ (АБОНЕНТА)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\n\n"
        << "  КЛАВИША UP - переключение на поле выше;" << std::endl
        << "  КЛАВИША DOWN - переключение на поле ниже;" << std::endl
        << "  КЛАВИША ENTER - подтвердить ввод;" << std::endl
        << "  КЛАВИША ESC - отменить ввод и вернуться в меню выбора действия;" << std::endl;

    std::string number = "", name = "", tariff = "";
    char ch;
    while (GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) >= 0)
    {
        std::string formatNumber = number;
        std::string formatName = name;
        std::string formatTariff = tariff;

        if (GetKeyState(VK_UP) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_BACK) < 0)
        {
            gotoxy(0, wherey() - 1);
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsoleHandle, (WORD)((0 << 4) | 15)); // Устанавливает цвет фона и текста
            if (selectedMenuItem == 1)
                std::cout << std::setw(65) << std::left << ("  НОМЕР: " + formatNumber) << std::endl;
            if (selectedMenuItem == 2)
                std::cout << std::setw(65) << std::left << "    ИМЯ: " + formatName;
            if (selectedMenuItem == 3)
                std::cout << std::setw(65) << std::left << "  ТАРИФ: " + formatTariff << std::endl;
            if (selectedMenuItem == 4)
                std::cout << "  ДОБАВИТЬ УЗЕЛ (АБОНЕНТА)" << std::endl;

            if (GetKeyState(VK_UP) < 0 && selectedMenuItem > 1)
                selectedMenuItem--;

            if ((GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) < 0) && selectedMenuItem < 4)
                selectedMenuItem++;

            if (GetKeyState(VK_BACK) < 0)
                switch (selectedMenuItem)
                {
                case 1:
                    if (number.length())
                        number.pop_back();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (name.length())
                        name.pop_back();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (tariff.length())
                        tariff.pop_back();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
        }
        while (GetKeyState(VK_UP) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_BACK) < 0) 
        { } // Чтобы не залипали соответствующие клавиши - крутить пустой циукл до тех пора пока соответствующие клавиши не будут отжаты.

        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsoleHandle, (WORD)((7 << 4) | 0));
        gotoxy(0, selectedMenuItem + 2);
        if (selectedMenuItem == 1)
            std::cout << std::setw(65) << std::left << ("  НОМЕР: " + formatNumber) << std::endl;
        if (selectedMenuItem == 2)
            std::cout << std::setw(65) << std::left << "    ИМЯ: " + formatName << std::endl;
        if (selectedMenuItem == 3)
            std::cout << std::setw(65) << std::left << "  ТАРИФ: " + formatTariff << std::endl;
        if (selectedMenuItem == 4)
            std::cout << "  ДОБАВИТЬ УЗЕЛ (АБОНЕНТА)" << std::endl;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsoleHandle, (WORD)((0 << 4) | 15));

        if (_kbhit())
        {
            ch = _getche();
            gotoxy(0, wherey());
            std::cout << " ";
            gotoxy(0, wherey());
            switch (selectedMenuItem)
            {
            case 1:
                if (number.length() < 11 && ch > 47 && ch < 58)
                    number += ch;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (((ch > 96 && ch < 123) || (ch > 64 && ch < 91) || ch == ' ') && !(GetKeyState(VK_UP) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_LEFT) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RIGHT) < 0))
                    name += ch;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (((ch > 96 && ch < 123) || (ch > 64 && ch < 91) || (ch > 47 && ch < 58) || ch == ' ') && !(GetKeyState(VK_UP) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_LEFT) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RIGHT) < 0))
                    tariff += ch;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Пример некорректной работы вышеприведенной программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Результата со второй гифки я добился путем добавления логической переменной flag, с помощью которой игнорируется первый символ который записывается в name и tariff, сразу после нажатия стрелки вниз или стрелки вверх. Но это решение меня не устраивает потому что оно не устраняет проблемы и часто не работает.

```
    bool flag = false; // Костыль, созданный исключительно ради того, чтобы показать что должно полуится
  ...
            if (GetKeyState(VK_UP) < 0 && selectedMenuItem > 1)
            {
                flag = false; 
                selectedMenuItem--;
            }
                
            if ((GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) < 0) && selectedMenuItem < 4)
            {
                flag = false;
                selectedMenuItem++;
            }
  ...
            case 1:
                if (number.length() < 11 && ch > 47 && ch < 58)
                    number += ch;
                flag = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (flag && ((ch > 96 && ch < 123) || (ch > 64 && ch < 91) || ch == ' ') && !(GetKeyState(VK_UP) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_LEFT) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RIGHT) < 0))
                    name += ch;
                flag = true;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (flag && ((ch > 96 && ch < 123) || (ch > 64 && ch < 91) || (ch > 47 && ch < 58) || ch == ' ') && !(GetKeyState(VK_UP) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_LEFT) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RIGHT) < 0))
                    tariff += ch;
                flag = true;
                break;
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что клавиш и их сочетаний много, так что для ряда клавиш `getch()` дает **2 кода** клавиш подряд. Так что если первый код равен 0x00 или 0xE0 - надо читать второй раз. См., например, этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573866/195342).